# Mechanism to test asynchronous replies

Tags: asynchronous, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

Let me provide a brief overview of the problem I'm struggling at the moment.
Assume we have an API endpoint (an async endpoint) which we are calling like this:

```
http POST 'http://localhost:8080/check_smth/?param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=null&param4=null&reply_to=http://some_url:some_port/' \
  Postman-Token:84dcfd8c-8e0a-438c-95ef-bc4d39809f35 \
  cache-control:no-cache
```

Once we hit the API endpoint some processing starts under the hood, when it's done it will notify URL that we have provided as a value to 
reply_to parameter

1. I'm wondering is there some built-in functionality in the Gatling tool that will allow me to specify some URL in request, that in turn will wait for that async process to finish?
2. If 1st item is not the case for the Gatling is it possible to poll somehow DB waiting for specific status and once it has changed, start processing another iteration of requests?

I'm sorry if it sounds silly and unprofessional, but I'm just getting started with Gatling. I will appreciate any thoughts on how to achieve/not achieve the desired result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to accept an incoming request, but you might be able to use the jdbc protocol to poll for a record to be present in the db